# Updating a Portion of a String in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, sql-update

I want to update the part of the string between the hyphens in SQL Server. So I have a column named `Supplier` with a value like this:

| Supplier |
| --- |
| test-abcd123-value |

I want to update it to:

| Supplier |
| --- |
| test-testing321-value |

How do you update query that?

Comment: With an `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: What is the SQL Server version and what is your current attempt?

Comment: are the values always in this format ? text1-text2-text3  ?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @Kairo, if you think that one of the answers is the best solution to your problem, you may [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. Only one answer can be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to get the positions of the hyphens using `CHARINDEX()` and update the text using `STUFF()` and appropriate calculations:

```
; WITH cte AS (
   SELECT
      Supplier,
      CHARINDEX('-', Supplier) AS p1, 
      CHARINDEX('-', Supplier, CHARINDEX('-', Supplier) + 1) AS p2
   FROM Data    
)  
UPDATE cte
SET Supplier = STUFF(Supplier, p1 + 1, p2 - p1 - 1, 'newvalue')  
WHERE p1 > 0 AND p2 > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find the positions of the hyphens,
with that get the part you want to replace,
and then use the replace function

The query below shows all the necessary stages that you need

```
declare @test table (supplier varchar(50))

insert into @test (supplier) values ('test-abcd123-value'), ('test-yaddyyaddy-value2'), ('test-bla bla bla-value'), ('test-nothing')

select t.supplier,
       t.startpos,
       t.length,
       substring(t.supplier, t.startpos, t.length) as to_replace,
       replace(t.supplier, substring(t.supplier, t.startpos, t.length), 'testing321') end_result
       -- it would be so nice if you could write it like this, but you have te repeat the statement above here or make yet another subquery
       --replace(t.supplier, to_replace, 'testing321') end_result

from   ( select t.supplier,
                charindex('-', supplier) + 1 startpos,
                (charindex('-', supplier, charindex('-', supplier) + 1)) - (charindex('-', supplier)) - 1 length  
         from   @test t
       ) t  
where  t.startpos > 0
and    t.length > 0
```

this results in

| supplier | startpos | length | to_replace | end_result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test-abcd123-value | 6 | 7 | abcd123 | test-testing321-value |
| test-yaddyyaddy-value2 | 6 | 10 | yaddyyaddy | test-testing321-value2 |
| test-bla bla bla-value | 6 | 11 | bla bla bla | test-testing321-value |

in case you want to show all rows, also the ones you can not replace, you can use this

```
declare @test table (supplier varchar(50))

insert into @test (supplier) values ('test-abcd123-value'), ('test-yaddyyaddy-value2'), ('test-bla bla bla-value'), ('test-nothing')

select t.supplier,
       t.startpos,
       t.length,
       
       case when t.startpos > 0 and t.length > 0 then
                 substring(t.supplier, t.startpos, t.length)
            else null
       end as to_replace,
       
       case when t.startpos > 0 and t.length > 0 then
                 replace(t.supplier, substring(t.supplier, t.startpos, t.length), 'testing321')
            else t.supplier
       end as end_result
from   ( select t.supplier,
                charindex('-', supplier) + 1 startpos,
                (charindex('-', supplier, charindex('-', supplier) + 1)) - (charindex('-', supplier)) - 1 length  
         from   @test t
       ) t
```

and the result is

| supplier | startpos | length | to_replace | end_result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test-abcd123-value | 6 | 7 | abcd123 | test-testing321-value |
| test-yaddyyaddy-value2 | 6 | 10 | yaddyyaddy | test-testing321-value2 |
| test-bla bla bla-value | 6 | 11 | bla bla bla | test-testing321-value |
| test-nothing | 6 | -6 |  | test-nothing |

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards due to the use of the `CONCAT_WS()` function. If needed, it is very easy to switch to the older `CONCAT()` function.

It is using *tokenization* via XML/XQuery, and checking for exact count of tokens in the column.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, supplier VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @tbl (supplier) VALUES 
('FirstToken-abcd123-ThirdToken'), 
('FirstToken-yaddyyaddy-ThirdToken'), 
('FirstToken-bla bla bla-ThirdToken'), 
('FirstToken-DoNothing');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '-'
    , @replaceWith varchar(20) = 'NewMiddleToken';

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *
        , new_supplier = CONCAT_WS(@separator
            , c.value('(/root/r[1]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)')
            , @replaceWith
            , c.value('(/root/r[3]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)'))
    FROM @tbl AS t
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
              REPLACE(supplier, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
              ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT c.value('count(/root/r)', 'INT')) AS t3(cnt)
    WHERE cnt = 3
)
UPDATE t
SET t.supplier = rs.new_supplier
FROM @tbl AS t INNER JOIN 
    rs ON t.ID = rs.ID;

--after
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

| ID | supplier |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | FirstToken-NewMiddleToken-ThirdToken |
| 2 | FirstToken-NewMiddleToken-ThirdToken |
| 3 | FirstToken-NewMiddleToken-ThirdToken |
| 4 | FirstToken-DoNothing |